# strpos or preg_match when trying find a string with sequence of numbers at the end?

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-match, strpos

I'm trying to create an IF statement when there is a string within the current URL which is partly working but returning some unwanted results.

```
// set patterns active
if ( $option == 'pattern' ) {
$patternvalue = "pattern=" . $v['id'];
$optionset = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $patternvalue);
if ($optionset !== false) {
echo ' class="active" ';
}
}
```

Using the above code if the pattern=16 then the code is echoing the class="active" for pattern=16 but also pattern=1... It seems to be matching only up to the first number.

I don't know if I should be using preg_match instead but am an complete novice and don't quite know how to get it working with all the back and forward slashes required.

A typical url ending may look like: /?action=search&pattern=23&fabric=13&type=2

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way.

```
/* parse_url(); Parse a URL and return its components */
$parse = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

/* parse_str(); Parses the string into variables */
parse_str($parse['query'], $query); 

if($query["pattern"] == $v['id']){
    echo 'class="active"';
}
```

[parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) - [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

**Edit: various examples.**

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/index.php?test1=1&test2=2&test3=3&test4=1";

$parse = parse_url($url);
print_r($parse);
/*
print_r($parse); output (array):
    Array
    (
        [scheme] => https
        [host] => www.example.com
        [path] => /index.php
        [query] => test1=1&test2=2&test3=3&test4=1
    )
*/
parse_str($parse['query'], $query);
print_r($query);
/*
print_r($query); output (array):
Array
(
    [test1] => 1
    [test2] => 2
    [test3] => 3
    [test4] => 1
)
*/

// Version 1 - ?test1=1
if($query["test1"] == 1){
    echo 'class="active1"'."\n"; /* output: class="active1" */
}

// Version 2 - ?test1=1&test2=2
if($query["test1"] == 1 && $query["test2"] == 2){
    echo 'class="active2"'."\n"; /* output: class="active2" */
}

// Version 3 ?test1=1  <<and>> $option list control.
$options = array("a","b","c");
if($query["test1"] == 1 && in_array("a", $options)){
    echo 'class="active3"'."\n"; /* output: class="active3" */
}

// Version 4 &test3=3 <<< value control.
if(in_array("3", $query)){
    echo 'class="active4"'."\n"; /* output: class="active4" */
}

// Version 5 ?test1  <<< test1 query >>> found in url
if(array_key_exists("test1",$query)){
    echo 'class="active5"'."\n"; /* output: class="active5" */
}

// Version 6 - ?ASDASDASD=  <<< not found.
if(array_key_exists("ASDASDASD",$query)){
    echo 'class="active6"'."\n"; /* not printed */
}

// Version 7 - advanced conditions
if($query["test1"] == 1){
    if($query["test2"] == 2){
        echo 'class="active7"'."\n"; /* output: class="active7" */
    }
}else{
    if($query["test3"] == 2){
        echo 'class="active8"'."\n"; /* not printed */
    }
}

// Version 9 -- multiple and advanced conditions
if(!empty($query["test1"]) && $query["test2"] == 2){

    echo 'class="active9"'."\n"; /* output: class="active9" */

}else if(empty($query["test2"]) && $query["test3"] == 3){

    echo 'class="active10"'."\n"; /* not printed */

}else{

    echo 'class="active11"'."\n"; /* not printed */

}
```

Comment: You beat me for second. +1

Comment: If I knew it, I would wait for you. :)

Comment: Your answer look like correct, It would be more useful for future reference if you explain it lil bit more.

Comment: @Smartpal I did not have time. But you are right. I added a few comments.

Comment: This seems to work well within the individual options but if two categories have the same ID then all are set as active e.g. pattern=15&type=15. I've wrapped them in the code if ( $option == 'pattern' ) { //code here } but not sure if that's the best approach?

Comment: @RyanMalone I edited a my reply. I hope the samples I've prepared will help you.